# Set window text color in Windows 8 Pro

Tags: windows-8, colors

Here is my problem:
[image]

The text is barely readable. I want to make the text white. I know there is no *normal* way of doing this, but is it possible to 'hack' this? I.e. find the config file that holds these color values (supposedly HEX or RGB) and change them manually?

What a disappointment that MS didn't think of this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no fix for it **WITHOUT using a modified theme**. You must use UxStyle to get other themes working. Here is a theme which fixes your issue:

[**Windows 8 default theme - Fix for dark title bars**](http://maddada1.deviantart.com/art/Windows-8-default-theme-Fix-for-dark-title-bars-347611536)

[image]

Comment: @DJDavid98 for 8.1, use this theme: http://pacmanix.deviantart.com/art/Windows-8-1-Update-1-Dark-458157744

Comment: @DJDavid98 but old Win8 themes don't support the new features from the larger 8.1 update: http://www.askvg.com/fix-context-menu-doesnt-appear-when-you-right-click-on-start-screen-in-windows-8-1/

Comment: The New link to the [Dark Gray Devian Art](https://www.deviantart.com/eversins/art/GreyEveTheme-FINAL-Windows-10-High-Contrast-Theme-643504863).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is a known problem and has been dealt with in other forums.

There is a tool called [UxStyle](http://www.uxstyle.com/) that should be able to fix it (I've not tried it personally).

Alternatively, try [Aero8Tuner](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.95).

Comment: I would like to solve this without any third-party programmes.

Comment: Why? It is a one-off change anyway. Just delete the app after you've made the change.

Comment: I didn't notice anything in Aero8Tuner that would actually solve the titlebar text issue when setting window colour to black.